# How to access specific values in a nested functor (Prolog)

Tags: prolog, member, functor

let's say we have this list of nested functors :

```
[state(a, [move(0, b), move(1, a)], b),
 state(b, [move(1, c), move(2, b)], c)].
```

What is the correct syntax to find out whether `move(1,a)` is in this list or rather if we know that `move(1, _)` is there, how can we find out what _'s value is?

I know that we can use the member function to find out if c is in the list of functors, but how can we apply this to a list of nested functors?

Comment: Just match. `member(state(a, [move(0,b), move(1,X)], b), ListOfFunctors)` for example...

Answer (score 0):

for example:

```
?- L=[state(a, [move(0, b), move(1, a)], b), state(b, [move(1, c), move(2, b)], c)],
member(state(S, Moves, _), L), member(move(1, T), Moves).
```

and we get (I abbreviated the output of `L`)

```
L = ...,
S = T, T = a,
Moves = [move(0, b), move(1, a)] ;
L = ...,
S = b,
Moves = [move(1, c), move(2, b)],
T = c ;
false.
```